# npm run build in windows 10

Tags: node.js, json, npm

This is the error I got when I execute the command in windows 10

```
 npm ERR! code EJSONPARSE
        npm ERR! file C:\Users\Dana\Desktop\Bootstrap_Coursera\Bootstrap4\conFusion\package.json
        npm ERR! JSON.parse Failed to parse json
        npm ERR! JSON.parse Unexpected token } in JSON at position 886 while parsing near '... npm 
        run usemin",
        npm ERR! JSON.parse   },
        npm ERR! JSON.parse   "author": "",
        npm ERR! JSON.parse  ...'
        npm ERR! JSON.parse Failed to parse package.json data.
        npm ERR! JSON.parse package.json must be actual JSON, not just JavaScript.
```

Comment: show package.json

Comment: "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "cssmin": "^0.4.3",
    "htmlmin": "0.0.7",
    "lite-server": "^2.6.1",
    "node-sass": "^5.0.0",
    "onchange": "^3.3.0",
    "parallelshell": "^3.0.1",
    "rimraf": "^2.6.2",
    "uglifyjs": "^2.4.11",
    "usemin-cli": "^0.5.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.3",
    "bootstrap-social": "^5.1.1",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "popper.js": "^1.12.9"
  }

Comment: @Fede in the future you should update your post with the requested info vs. just pasting it in the comments

Answer (score 0):

There's an excess comma after `npm run usemin"` (on the line with `... npm run usemin",`) in your `package.json` file. You have to remove this comma, since JSON does not allow trailing commas, causing a JSON parsing error.

Comment: you were right. Thank you very much. Now I have another error, go to other post.